# gitlab.com reporting incorrect repository size

Tags: gitlab

We have a (private) repository on GitLab that is our template for starting new projects. Today, one of our developers attempted to push a commit, and got a message about exceeding the repository size limit. Checking on the GitLab web UI, it did indeed say that the repository was using 13.7 GB on both "files" and "storage" (the limit being 10 GB). After attempting a repository "housekeeping" run, this increased to 15.1 GB (I have no idea if this was as a result of the "housekeeping" or if the timing is coincidental, but that's beside the point).

This number seems to be very wrong to me:

- The .git folder in the checked out project is approx. 540 MB
- 3 projects that were forked from this template project within the last month or so (and have had some large binary files added since) are reporting between 1 and 2 GB each
- Running git-sizer on the checked out project says the total size of all blobs is 986 MiB, with the total size of the biggest checkout being 758 MiB
- Exporting the entire repository from GitLab results in a 1.82 GB tar.gz file

The only significant work that's gone on since the aforementioned forks did require adding a few moderately large (tens of MB) files, but even after deleting that branch and running "housekeeping" again, the reported size of the repository has not dropped.

The repository has no wiki, no CI/CD, no package, and only a hand full of merge requests and issues.

Is there anything that I'm missing that could be causing ~14 GB of data to be reported? Or is there any way to force GitLab to recalculate the size of the repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A git repository size on remote includes loose objects, whereas if you're working locally (or off of a fork), you likely don't have those loose objects, or they were cleaned up.

Most of the time, you only have a copy of the default branch and whatever branches you've worked on locally, not *every* branch that has been pushed to the remote.

You can follow the [GitLab documentation on reducing repository size](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/reducing_the_repo_size_using_git.html).

The [comment from a Backend Engineer on this repository cleanup issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/220104#note_452931122) may also help explain what's happening a little further. The key thing from this comment is that you need to *wait 30 minutes* after following the documented instructions for the Housekeeping/cleanup job to work properly.

Comment: I looked through the docs yesterday, but didn't go through the `filter-repo` process as no large files had been added recently, and given the very recent and sudden increase in reported repo size, it seemed more like an anomaly than an actual repo size issue.
I've run through that now, and it does seem to have fixed the issue. I had to upload the commit-map file and run cleanup (reduced the repo from 15.1 GB to ~500 MB) before I could force push `refs/replace/*` (which increased repo size to 1.4 GB, which does feel more likely) as the push was rejected due to exceeding repository size limits.

Comment: I've not been paying attention to the reported repository size until now, but is this cleanup process something we should be doing periodically (every 6 months to a year) to prune loose objects on active repositories?

Comment: Not necessarily. Housekeeping also happens automatically with a set number of commits and prune works automatically but is set to 2 weeks by default. The issue is that if anyone does a large commit, even an accidental one, you can't remedy it immediately any other way.

Comment: Hmm. It seems strange that it was able to so quickly get past the 10 GB limit (initially to 13.7 GB, then 15.1 GB). The last commits that did go in before it started rejecting pushes were pretty small, though there were some slightly bigger ones in the preceding few days, but nothing thats multiple gigabytes in size.